# How can I write to a remote file?

Tags: c#, file-io, remote-access

I need to be able to write to a remote text file located on my vps. I know how to read the file using WebRequest, WebResponse.  It's probably something really simple.

Comment: I believe the more appropriate term is, remote not external.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Jeff. @Felice Yes, it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to: Upload Files with FTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestGetExample
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
            byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you hope to get thumb ups by editing your post with a big copy-paste, right ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since its an VPS (Remote machine), there isnt a direct API or way to do it. Either via telnet or FTP server ways.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at msdn's documentation for [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest%28v=VS.80%29.aspx#Y2052), which has examples on uploading, downloading and deleting files via ftp.

There's also HttpRequests with file attachments (which is what e.g. many avatar uploading forms use).